# how to remove spaces from xml file while parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i have used the recommend line of code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSMutableString *)string
{
// save the characters for the current item...
if ( [currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) 
{
    currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    if ([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] > 0) {
        [currentNodeContent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
      }
    NSLog(@"currentnode content...%@",currentNodeContent);    
    [blogtitle addObject:currentNodeContent];
    NSLog(@"%@",blogtitle);
 }
```

t still i am getting the empty value in array. i guess the initialization of string 'currentNodeContent' should be somewhere else.

Comment: Just don't add empty strings to your array. Check for length before adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSMutableString *)string
{
// save the characters for the current item...
if ( [currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) 
{
    NSString *newString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet    whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if ([newString length] > 0) 
    {
        [blogtitle addObject:newString];
    }         

    NSLog(@"currentnode content...%@",currentNodeContent);    

    NSLog(@"%@",blogtitle);
 }
```

Comment: You should store the trimmed string to avoid trimming it twice.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Georg, what I meant was just give a check of the string's length, I didn't thought of the code, I appreciate your comment so that I can improve my way of answering.., Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check for, and only add, non-empty string with for example `[currentNodeContent length] > 0`, in your `NSXMLParserDelegate`.